# Excel Userform runs Button1_Enter when tab to Button1 (without hitting Enter)

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have created a small UserForm in Excel. I have created Button1 and have enabled the tab index. When I tab from a drop down box to Button1, it assumes that I have hit enter on the button, just by simply tabbing to it. Is there a way to disable this?

I want the user to tab to Button1 and then actually hit Enter or click. I am not sure why simply clicking tab after previous item is running the macro in Button1_Enter.

Thanks.

Comment: "Enter" here means "about to get focus" (i.e. you are about to "go in to" the control), not "user pressed enter"

Answer (score 0):

Place you code in the `Button1_Click` event instead of the `Button1_Enter`. As Tim points out, "Enter" refers to receiving focus and not clicking of the button hence the behavior you've described.